# compute_totals returns the wrong total derivatives when approx_totals is not used

Tags: openmdao

I noticed that `prob.compute_totals()` returns a wrong answer when `prob.model.approx_totals()` is not specified before. Having the partial derivative manually defined or computed by finite differences doesn't change anything, the answer remains wrong when not calling `prob.model.approx_totals()` before. Also, the call to `compute_totals` is actually faster when `approx_totals` is called before, compared to when it's not. This seems counter-intuitive with manually defined partials, since `approx_totals` is supposed to add an unnecessary finite-difference computation.

Here is a MWE with the Sellar example taken from the OpenMDAO documentation. I also noticed the same behaviour in OpenAeroStruct, even though the differences are smaller than in this example.

```
import openmdao.api as om
from openmdao.test_suite.components.sellar_feature import SellarMDA

prob = om.Problem()
prob.model = SellarMDA()

prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-8

prob.model.add_design_var('x', lower=0, upper=10)
prob.model.add_design_var('z', lower=0, upper=10)
prob.model.add_objective('obj')
prob.model.add_constraint('con1', upper=0)
prob.model.add_constraint('con2', upper=0)

prob.setup()
prob.set_solver_print(level=0)

prob.model.approx_totals() # Commenting this line gives the wrong result

prob.run_driver()
totals = prob.compute_totals(of=['obj'],wrt=['x','z'])

print("""
Obj = {}
x = {}
z = {}
y1 = {}
y2 = {}
Totals = {}""".format(prob['obj'][0],prob['x'][0],prob['z'][0],prob['y1'][0],prob['y2'][0],totals))
```

The good result, with `approx_totals` :

```
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 3.183393951729169
            Iterations: 6
            Function evaluations: 6
            Gradient evaluations: 6
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------

Obj = 3.183393951729169
x = 0.0
z = 1.977638883487764
y1 = 3.1600000000897133
y2 = 3.755277766976125
Totals = OrderedDict([(('obj', 'x'), array([[0.94051147]])), (('obj', 'z'), array([[3.50849282, 1.72901602]]))])
```

The wrong result, whithout `approx_totals` :

```
Optimization terminated successfully.    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 3.1833939532752136
            Iterations: 11
            Function evaluations: 12
            Gradient evaluations: 11
Optimization Complete
-----------------------------------

Obj = 3.1833939532752136
x = 4.401421628747386e-15
z = 1.9776388839289216
y1 = 3.1600000016563765
y2 = 3.755277767857951
Totals = OrderedDict([(('obj', 'x'), array([[0.99341446]])), (('obj', 'z'), array([[3.90585351, 1.97002055]]))])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, the problem is that you have a cycle in SellarMDA, but the model does not contain a linear solver that can compute the total derivatives across the cycle. One way you can check on this is to run "openmdao check myfilename.py" at the command-line.  I ran it on your model, and got the following warnings:

```
INFO: checking comp_has_no_outputs
INFO: checking dup_inputs
INFO: checking missing_recorders
WARNING: The Problem has no recorder of any kind attached
INFO: checking out_of_order
INFO: checking solvers
WARNING: Group 'cycle' contains cycles [['d1', 'd2']], but does not have an iterative linear solver.
INFO: checking system
```

There are a couple of remedies for this. You could manually add a different linear solver such as `DirectSolver` or `PETScKrylov` to the "cycle" group.  You could also import `SellarMDALinearSolver` instead of `SellarMDA`.  SellarMDALinearSolver uses a Newton solver for converging the cycle, and a DirectSolver for computing the derivatives.  SellarMDA uses NonlinearBlockGS to converge the cycle, but unfortunately does not contain an appropriate linear solver to compute the derivatives.  These components are used in a variety of testing roles, but I think in retrospect, we should probably add a LinearBlockGS to SellarMDA in the future, so that total derivatives can be computed without modification.  For now though, you'll have to use SellarMDALinearSolver or add the solver yourself.

BTW, I suspect the optimization was slower because the derivatives were so bad.  It took twice as many iterations, though it still somehow managed to get pretty close to the answer.

You mentioned similar symptoms in your OpenAeroStruct model.  I would suspect that either 1) a subcomponent has an error in its analytical derivatives, or 2) the linear solvers are not set up correctly (maybe you have a cycle somewhere without a good linear solver in that group or parent group.)  I think that `Problem.check_partials` and `Problem.check_totals` will give you more insight on where the problem could be.  There is more info on these [here.](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/working_with_derivatives/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not know I needed to specify a linear solver when working with analytic derivatives.
Concerning OpenAeroStruct, `check_totals` tells me that the derivatives are ok. I guess the small differences I noticed in the total derivatives just come from analytic derivatives vs finite differences. I just thought that I had a problem with `approx_totals` and `compute_totals`, and I didn't seek any further.